2018 world cup goals scored by country python dict
I have a .txt file with all goals scored in the 2018 world cup, there are 169 lines in this file structured as:
playername;country;minute;
EG:
Gazinsky;Russia;12;
Cheryshev;Russia;43;
Cheryshev;Russia;91;
Dzyuba;Russia;71;
Golovin;Russia;94;
Gimenez;Uruguay;89;
Cheryshev;Russia;59;
Dzyuba;Russia;62;
OG;Russia;47;
Salah;Egypt;73;

(The minute is the minute the goal was scored)
I want to create a Quiz() function that iterates over each line in this .txt file and adds each country to a python dictionary, and adds the number of goals scored for each country: for example
{Russia: 11},
{England: 12},
{Croatia: 14},
etc.

(the number of goals scored is simply the number of times they appear in the .txt file.)
I would then choose two random countries and ask the user to guess which country scored more goals in the world cup.
Here is the code I have so far:
import random 

def Quiz():
    # randomly pick two countries from the world cup
    # ask the user to guess which country scored more goals in 2018 world cup


    countries = []
    file = open("Goals.txt", "r")

    for line in file:
        data = line.split(";")
        country = data[1]
        countries.append(country)
    file.close()

    # Randomly generating the countries
    countries = list(dict.fromkeys(countries))
    country_1 = random.choice(countries)
    country_2 = random.choice(countries)
    if country_1 == country_2:
        country_2 = random.random(countries)

    print("Which country scored more goals in the 2018 world cup?")
    print(country_1)
    print("OR")
    print(country_2)
    userInput = input("Answer: ").title()


I need help with creating this dictionary, and then using the users input to work out if they were correct or not. Any help massively appreciated!

Your example is not a dictionary, but a bunch of dictionaries, one for each country.

We prefer specific questions about a concrete problem with code you have written. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Actually, it's not even a bunch of dictionaries.  All you have created is a list of country names.  There are no dictionaries in the code you posted.  If you created a dictionary with the name as the key and the number of goals as the value, this could work.

Maybe try splitting your problem in 2: 1) a version of the program that has the dictionary defined in it (i.e. doesn't use the external file), and 2) the code to create that dictionary from the file.

@TimRoberts: the example data is a bunch of dictionaries; the example code produces a list of countries.

For creating the dict, see Using a dictionary to count the items in a list. I would use a Counter, myself. To get to that question I googled "python count number of occurrences in list" and looked around a bit. In the future, please start with your own research. See [ask] for more tips.

@tripleee FYI you can write [ask] to get [ask]. More shorthands listed here.

Sidenote: Best practice for opening files is using with like with open(filename) as file: for line in file: .... It's covered in the official tutorial here.

I've separated the "read the data" part from the "run the quiz" part, so you can reuse it.  I've also used a collections.Counter to create the counts you want.
import collections
import random 

def ingest():
    countries = collections.Counter()
    for line in open('goals.txt'):
        data = line.split(';')
        countries[data[1]] += 1

    return countries


def Quiz(countries):
    # randomly pick two countries from the world cup
    # ask the user to guess which country scored more goals in 2018 world cup


    # Randomly generating the countries
    names = list(countries)
    country_1 = random.choice(names)
    country_2 = random.choice(names)
    if country_1 == country_2:
        country_2 = random.choice(names)

    print("Which country scored more goals in the 2018 world cup?")
    print(country_1)
    print("OR")
    print(country_2)
    userInput = input("Answer: ").title()

c = ingest()
Quiz(c)


you will need a dictionary that will store number of goals and a list that will store list of countries. Please use code below as a guidance.
import random 


# goals by country
goals = {}

# open file inside `with` context
with open("Goals.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data = line.split(";")
        country = data[1]
        if country not in goals:
            # country not seen yet. This will create a dictionary key
            goals[country] = 0
        
        # add a goal to the country
        goals[country] += 1
# stores all contries in a list   
countries = list(goals.keys())


def Quiz(goals = goals, countries = countries):    
    # randomly pick two countries from the world cup
    # ask the user to guess which country scored more goals in 2018 world cup

    # Randomly generating the countries
    country_1 = random.choice(countries)
    country_2 = random.choice(countries)

    # use `while` instead of `if`. It will iterate until it will get a different country
    while country_1 == country_2:
        country_2 =  random.choice(countries)
     
    # get the winner given two selected countries
    if goals[country_2] > goals[country_1]:
        win_country = country_2
    elif goals[country_2] < goals[country_1]:
        win_country = country_1
    else:
        win_country = "same number of goals"



    print("Which country scored more goals in the 2018 world cup?")
    print(country_1)
    print("OR")
    print(country_2)
    userInput = input("Answer: ").title()
    print("Correct answer: ", win_country)

Quiz()


The global statement is entirely unnecessary, since you aren't changing countries here.

Yup, I know. It is more for improving readibility, to show that the var wasn't defined in the function.
